# Get request returning object with time delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am using following get service ..

```
fieldServices.factory('serverField', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return {
      particularField : $resource('http://localhost:8080/Omniview/rest/fields/:fieldId', {}, {
          get: {method:'GET', isArray:false}
      })
};
}]);
```

Here is my controller to use the get data :

```
$scope.allFields;
serverField.fieldList.get(function(data){
    //console.log(data);
    $scope.allFields=data;
});
console.log($scope.allFields);
```

In above case It is giving me undefined as allFields is not set with data
but in below case:

```
$scope.allFields;
serverField.fieldList.get(function(data){
    //console.log(data);
    $scope.allFields=data;
});

setTimeout(function(){
      console.log($scope.allFields);
},1000)  ;
```

It is giving me the correct object .I don't know why .Can someone explain me why it is happening and how do I get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
$scope.allFields;
serverField.fieldList.get(function(data){
    $scope.allFields=data;
});
console.log($scope.allFields);
```

The `console.log` line is executed immediately after the `get` is fired, but before the server call returns a response. An "AJAX" call like that is asynchronous.

The function in your `get` is a success callback. This function gets executed when the server responds to your `get` request. Only then will `$scope.allFields` be set.

The reason the `setTimeout` "works" is because it doesn't take the server a second to respond to the request, so by the time that timeout fires, the success callback will have fired.

This asynchronous behavior can be seen when you run this code:

```
console.log('1 - Before get');
serverField.fieldList.get(function(data){
    console.log('2 - Get success callback');
});
console.log('3 - After get');
```

You'll see those lines logged in this order:

```
1 - Before get
3 - After get
2 - Get success callback
```

Comment: So how do I resolve this ,I need to access the get success callback data just after the service call ?

Comment: You can access that in the function where I placed that `console.log('2 - Get success callback');`

Answer (score 0):

Simple, the get call is asynchronous. If you don't introduce a delay, chances are that the async call is still waiting to return - hence, $scope.allFields is undefined.

But if you do introduce a delay, chances are that the async call has returned by the time you log to the console - and chances increase the longer you wait.